# Is spiked tensor decomposition a special case of INDSCAL decomposition?

Tags: feature-selection, matrix-decomposition, tensor

I understand that "Spiked" often refers to the presence of a dominant component (or a few dominant components) in a tensor decomposition. Spiked tensor decomposition is applied to multi-way tensor data, to extract the principal components along each mode/dimension. One of the modes typically represents multiple subjects making measurements.

On the other side, INDSCAL (Individual Differences Scaling) is a specific type of tensor decomposition used in the context of multiway data analysis, particularly in psychological and social sciences. It is designed to model individual differences in the data.

Can we see spiked tensor decomposition as a specialized application of INDSCAL, where the goal is dimensionality reduction rather than modeling personal differences? The extracted components will represent the primary latent patterns, similar to the "group stimulus space" in INDSCAL.

Thanks.